# Is there a way to see how node js stores numbers internally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point

I'm working on improving my understanding of floating points in Node. My understanding is that *every* number in javascript is stored as a 64-bit floating point (which is kind of insane, and pretty cool) and I want to play around with these a little bit.

Is there an easy way to print out how an arbitrary number is stored internally? Something like (5).toFloatRepresentation() which would return `101...`?

I looked around online and couldn't find anything -- if I missed something obvious, I apologize!

I know I could write a function that did this, but I'm interested in looking at things from the other side!

Thanks!

Comment: For integers `num.toString( 2 )` should work. Don't know about about decimals, though.

Comment: First of all, you are wrong thinking every number is stored as float. They can be stored as integer as well.

Comment: The ECMAScript specification doesn't distinguish between "floats" and "ints", yes, but that doesn't mean that all numbers are stored by JavaScript engines as floats. For performance reasons, many engines support an optimized integer type internally even if the difference is not visible from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that every number in javascript is stored as a 64-bit floating point

Sort of, kind of, not quite. The internal representation of numbers is quite complex. Initially V8 (the JavaScript engine node js is built on) used tagged pointers internally.

The trick is that pointers on 64-bit machine are aligned in such a way that the least three significat bits are 0. So you can store additional information in a pointer itself (e.g. whether it is a pointer or an integer).

So V8 stored integers and pointers on a stack, in the same 64-bit space. Note that since the last bit is used as a flag then integers in V8 were at most 61 bit (and AFAIK only 32 bit?). Doubles on the other hand were stored on the heap as separate objects.

On the other hand WebKit implementation now uses so called nan-boxing which stores pointers inside doubles. This follows from the observation that NaN has `2^53` different representations. You may ask how can you store 64-bit pointer (or actually 61-bit pointer) inside 53 bits? Well you can, because currently (i.e. because of small ram sizes) only 48 bits are used.

So in WebKit integers are indeed stored as doubles. But WebKit also has small integers stored on the stack (as proper integer types) in order to use them in loops and indexing. That's because integer operations are still at least as fast as float operations and in many cases faster.

Here's an interesting (quite outdated though) article that you may want to read:

https://wingolog.org/archives/2011/05/18/value-representation-in-javascript-implementations

> Is there an easy way to print out how an arbitrary number is stored internally?

No. Actually there is no way at all. As I've mentioned that totally depends on the JavaScript engine and there is no API in spec to retrieve that information. You can try to read [the source code](https://github.com/v8/v8) though.

> I know I could write a function that did this

You can't. Not in JavaScript anyway. Unless I'm really misunderstanding the question. The internal representation and what you see in JavaScript are two different worlds.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! What I meant by "write a function that did this" was write a function that could take in a number and return a 64-bit float representation of said number. That's all quite interesting, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get a visualisation of a floating point number:

```js
function getBinaryRepresentation(num) {
    // Store as float
    var buffer = new Float64Array([num]).buffer;
    // Retrieve as unsigned bytes
    var view   = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    // Convert bytes to string (binary representation)
    return view.reduceRight( 
        (arr, n) => arr.concat(('0000000' + n.toString(2)).substr(-8)), []
    ).join('');
}

function formatFloatBits(num) {
    var bits = getBinaryRepresentation(num);
    // Put spaces between the different parts: 
    // - sign (1 bit)
    // - exponent, with bias (11 bits)
    // - significand (52 bits), without most significant 1
    return bits[0] + ' ' + bits.slice(1, 12) + ' ' + bits.slice(12);
}

function print(num) {
    console.log(formatFloatBits(num));
}

// Examples:
print(0);
print(2);
print(2.1);
print(7);
print(-7);
```

Comment: Thank you! some very cool function calls here, I appreciate it a lot.